# Nuxt.js - Use plugin in component's story - Storybook

Tags: nuxt.js, storybook

How can I create a story of a component that uses nuxt plugin?

Let's say I want to use that nuxt plugin in template.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ $somePlugin('text') }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Plugin is declared in nuxt.config.js, and requires external library:

```
import externalLibrary from 'ext';

export default (context, inject) => {
  inject('somePlugin', (content) => {
    return externalLibrary(content);
  });
};
```

It end up with a type error `_vm.$somePlugin is not a function`.

How am I supposed to make it available for Storybook?

I am using @nuxtjs/storybook version 4.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that storybook requires plugin declared as a string.

```
// nuxt.config.js

plugins: ['~/plugin.js'] <- works

plugins: [{
  src: '~/plugin.js',
  mode: 'client',
},] <- won't work
```